# How can I set a UITableView's cell text to database cell's content in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, uitableview, swift

I am creating an iOS Pokémon database application using Swift, for my A2 computing coursework. Before this project, I have not used Swift, so I am teaching myself using relevant examples which I can hopefully copy and paste from.

I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and the [SQLite.swift library from Stephen Celis](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift).

One such test is producing a UITableView which can read from my pre-existing, pre-populated database.

I've managed to get the UITableView to create all the cells - and set the detailTextLabel to the indexPath (plus 1, so it starts at 1 and ends at 721 instead of starting at 0 and ending at 720). So I have 721 cells in the table just fine.

However, I can't seem to get the textLabel for each cell to display the correct data. Instead, it displays "SQLite.Expression" for each cell.

Above the ViewController class in the ViewController.swift file, I have

```
let db = Database("/Users/rhysmorgan/Documents/Coding/DatabaseLoadTest/Pokémon Database.sqlite", readonly: true)
let pokemonTable = db["Pokémon"]
let name = Expression<String>("PokéName")
let gen = Expression<Int>("Generation")
```

and in the main tableView function, I have

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let rowno: Int = indexPath.row + 1
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter(); formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 3
    let formattedrowno = formatter.stringFromNumber(rowno)
    let pokemonname = pokemonTable[name]


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(pokemonname)"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(formattedrowno!)"

    return cell
}
```

Is anybody able to help me?
With thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've managed to get it to display the correct value from the first row by wrapping

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(pokemonname)"
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(formattedrowno!)"
```

in a

```
for pokemon in pokemonTable {
/*insert above lines*/
}
```

loop and adding

```
println(pokemon[name])
```

produced every single record, printed its "PokéName" column data. It then repeated this another 13 times. So it printed the first record's "PokéName" column data all the way to the 721st column's "PokéName" data, looped back to the first and repeated this again. But still, the tableview's label text didn't update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered in your edit, a query must be executed to access the underlying data, which happens when you run the `for`–`in` loop. Instead of calling `for`–`in`, you can store the data in memory, *e.g.*:

```
let data = Array(pokemonTable)
let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
lazy var formatter: NSNumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 3
    return formatter
}()

func tableView(
    tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath
) -> UITableViewCell {
    let idx = indexPath.row
    let rowNo = formatter.stringFromNumber(idx + 1)
    let pokemonName = data[idx][name]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath
    ) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = pokemonName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = rowNo

    return cell
}
```

In this case, we're executing the SQL query once, storing all the rows in a `data` array (see the first line), and then accessing that array in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

---

And before your edit, for the sake of being complete, take a look at this line:

```
let pokemonname = pokemonTable[name]
```

This is creating a nested SQL identifier by sub-scripting the table name with the SQL identifier you defined earlier. In this case:

```
"Pokémon"."PokéName"
```

See the [Column Namespacing](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/eee33ef0e17005894f65bf85462298543ecc761e/Documentation/Index.md#column-namespacing) section of the documentation.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I read in your [documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#plucking-rows): "To collect all rows into an array, we can simply wrap the sequence (though this is not always the most memory-efficient idea). `let all = Array(users)`". Is there any more efficient solution to link sqlite data to UITableViews? In my case, I have a table with some thousands items, which I would to query/filter and show in the UITableView while typing.

Comment: @DanieleB You can fetch your data in batches (using limit/offset) and append them to the data source, reloading the table view each time if you merely want rows to start populating more quickly.

You could also make your table view delegate and data source smart about loading rows in batches as you scroll, but that's more boilerplate than you usually need.